# Eclipselink foreign key constraint violation but SQL insertion order seems fine

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink 2.6.3 (tried also with 2.6.2) and I'm facing a very strange situation where the database (Oracle 12c) complains with the following message:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LOG_SUB_LO_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found

However, when looking at the logs, they seem to suggest that the referred parent key should be there, they display the following:

```
2016-12-01 09:08:26,601 [grizzly-http-server-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.persistence.sql - INSERT INTO LOGS (ID, CREATION_DATE) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [4368, 2016-12-01 09:08:26.601]
2016-12-01 09:08:26,604 [grizzly-http-server-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.persistence.sql - INSERT INTO LOG_PARAM (ID, CREATION_DATE, LO_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4369, 2016-12-01 09:08:26.601, 4368]
2016-12-01 09:08:26,607 [grizzly-http-server-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.persistence.sql - INSERT INTO LOG_SUB (ID, CREATION_DATE, LO_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4370, 2016-12-01 09:08:26.601, 4368]
2016-12-01 09:08:26,624 [grizzly-http-server-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.persistence.sql - SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
2016-12-01 09:08:26,645 [grizzly-http-server-2] WARN  org.eclipse.persistence - 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException: 
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LOG_SUB_LO_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found

Error Code: 2291
Call: INSERT INTO LOG_SUB (ID, CREATION_DATE, LO_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4370, 2016-12-01 09:08:26.601, 4368]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatch(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatchedStatements(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.writesCompleted(DatabaseAccessor.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.commitTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicCommitTransaction(AbstractSession.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.basicCommitTransaction(ClientSession.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.commitTransaction(AbstractSession.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitTransaction(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitTransaction(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitTransactionAfterWriteChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1615)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LOG_SUB_LO_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
```

The tables are the following:

- LOGS (PK is ID)
- LOG_SUB (PK is ID and LO_ID is a FK to LOGS)
- LOG_PARAM (PK is ID and LO_ID is a FK to LOGS)

The mapping to JPA objects is relatively straightforward:

- `Log` class (which matches the LOGS table) with 2 `@OneToMany` relationships towards LogSub and LogParam which are flagged as cascade ALL
- `LogSub` (for LOG_SUB table) and `LogParam` (for LOG_PARAM table) both have a `@ManyToOne` relationship towards `Log` which are flagged as non-nullable and optional=false

I create my `Log` object and add 1 LogSub and 1 LogParam (one each relationship) and then persist my Log object.

When my transaction is committed, I randomly get the above error.

For info: I'm using EclipseLink with Spring-Jpa and Spring-Data and with JDBC batch writing enabled.

*I stripped some data for simplicity*

Please don't hesitate to ask more details if needed.

Comment: It is as if they are happening in different transactions. Try turning logging on to ALL or finest to see if anything else shows up.

Comment: Check your connection and transaction setup, as it appears these statements are not going into the same transaction.  Additional logging might help.